# Buying in app purchase dialog using test id does not appear after first attempt

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

I am using **anjlab/android-inapp-billing** library for my in app purchases.
On first attempt on clicking on ***Purchase Button*** in my activity, I was able to see the dialog appearing for buying.

In this dialog I get `testingId`.

[image: Testing purchase]

On clicking The **BUY button**, I have seen two options then Ok.

The first attempt was successful.

Now after first successful bought item if I click on ***Purchase Button***
this dialog does not appear.

Why this `dialog` is not showing?

this is my code

```
final AlertDialog.Builder builder2 = new AlertDialog.Builder(StartActivity.this);

            LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
            View dialogLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.adremover_layout, null);
            builder2.setTitle("Clear Ads");
            builder2.setMessage("Buy Products");
            builder2.setView(dialogLayout);
            builder2.setIcon(R.drawable.dupiconf);
            Button btn_buy1 = (Button)dialogLayout.findViewById(R.id.buyitem_btn1);
            Button btn_buy2 = (Button)dialogLayout.findViewById(R.id.buyitem_btn2);
            Button btn_buy3 = (Button)dialogLayout.findViewById(R.id.buyitem_btn3);


            btn_buy1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {


                    editor1 = getSharedPreferences(FIRST_BUY, MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
                    editor1.putString("product", "item1");
                    editor1.apply();

                    getpurchaseitem = "itm1";


                    bp.purchase(StartActivity.this, "android.test.purchased");
                }
            });


            btn_buy2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {


                    editor1 = getSharedPreferences(FIRST_BUY, MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
                    editor1.putString("product", "item2");
                    editor1.apply();

                    getpurchaseitem = "itm2";

                    bp.purchase(StartActivity.this, "android.test.purchased");
                }
            });


            btn_buy3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    editor1 = getSharedPreferences(FIRST_BUY, MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
                    editor1.putString("product", "item3");
                    editor1.apply();

                    getpurchaseitem = "itm3";

                    bp.purchase(StartActivity.this, "android.test.purchased");

                }
            });

            alert2 = builder2.create();
            alert2.show();
```

Even after uninstalling the app the dialog for buying does not appear.

```
@Override
    public void onProductPurchased(@NonNull String productId, @Nullable TransactionDetails details) {


if(getpurchaseitem == "itm1")
{

    CancelAlarm();

}

else if (getpurchaseitem == "itm2")
{

    CancelAlarm();

}
else if(getpurchaseitem == "itm3")
{

    CancelAlarm();
}



    }
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you are not waiting for the BillingProcessor object to be initialized. this is why it works for the second time.

How to use [BillingProcessor.IBillingHandle](https://github.com/anjlab/android-inapp-billing-v3)